# Database communication class as a singleton

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, singleton

Im considering, whether class which gonna communicate with database should be a singleton.

Instead of injecting context everywhere it's needed, I've created one inside Database class, which is the singleton class.

Is it good practice?

Code:

```
    class DatabaseService
{
    public FreelanceOrganizerDataContext DatabaseContext { get; private set; } = new FreelanceOrganizerDataContext();
    static DatabaseService _singleton = new DatabaseService();
    private DatabaseService() { }

    public static DatabaseService GetDatabaseService()
    {
        return _singleton;
    }

    //Save Section
    public void AddProject()
    {

    }

    public void AddCustomer()
    {

    }

    //etc

}
```

Comment: Singletons are usually a bad idea.  Google has a tool to find them and root them out of their code.  It's one of the GoF patterns that would be voted off the island today, 21 years later.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you tell me something more about constraints of such solution in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an IoC such as [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx) or [Autofac](https://autofac.org). You can do things such as Inject Dependecies into your classes, control the lifecycle of the objects (when and how often they are instantiated), and better set yourself up for Unit Tests.

Comment: Whole app is based on MVVM pattern- should I create service classes (communicating with database) for each model class, which contains a reference to DbContext object, injected by an IoC container?